# Vim solarized looks wrong

Tags: vim, solarized

I have downloaded and set up vim solarized. But I get a weird output:

[image]

The background of some keywords are slightly darker than the rest, and surprisingly everything else is in bold. How to fix this?

Comment: What OS, what terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue by adding this line to the `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set t_Co=256
```